# Hyperledger fabric build error

Tags: docker, go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have followed the installation & configuration of hyperledger fabric from http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io and completed the installation. When I tried to build it I am getting error. Could you let me know the resolution.

To build Hyperledger Fabric:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
make dist-clean all
```

Error output:

```
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-tools hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0-rc2-snapshot-4709b33
Checking committed files for SPDX-License-Identifier headers ...
The following files are missing SPDX-License-Identifier headers:
orderer/multichain/manager.go
orderer/multichain/manager_test.go

Please replace the Apache license header comment text with:
SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
Makefile:111: recipe for target 'license' failed
make: *** [license] Error 1
```

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to report such issues into bug tracker: https://jira.hyperledger.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa, for now opened a JIRA tickets: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5282

Answer (score 5):

Try to run:

`make peer orderer peer-docker orderer-docker tools-docker configtxgen cryptogen`,

instead. This will skip license validation part and will allow you to build necessary building blocks.

PS. Meanwhile I've opened a [JIRA](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5282)  to get it fixed and [change request](https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/11577/): with actual fix.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the following files

```
orderer/multichain/manager.go
orderer/multichain/manager_test.go
```

Add the following lines in the beginning

```
/*
Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.

SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
```

You can also check if the error is resolved by running following command from fabric

```
make license
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
 `make release`
 and then `make docker`